# Linking to another page in pdf abcpdf8

Tags: html, .net, razor, abcpdf

I'm trying to create a link in a pdf to another page from a .Net cshtml file. after some research I've found that the best way to go about this seems to be:

```
<a annots="goto:@pageNumber"> @pageNumber </a>
```

However, this doesn't seem to do anything when i generate the pdf.
Any ideas why?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

To target an HTML link to a specific page in a PDF file, add `#page=[page number]` to the end of the link's URL.

For example, this HTML tag opens page 4 of a PDF file named myfile.pdf:

`<A HREF="http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf#page=4">`

Comment: The problem with this is that I need to view the pdf within an embedded viewer, and doing it this way links to the correct page but in a different browser tab

Comment: Ohh, I see. These might have some valuable info: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

https://www.abeautifulsite.net/link-to-a-specific-page-in-a-pdf-file

Comment: also navigating to the page using #page=[page number] doesn't seem to work at all in Edge. Any ideas how I could work around that?

Comment: It seems to be a browser issue. Seems to be more people out there with the same problem, and no solution... :(